# Oracle date format implementation

Tags: java, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Oracle date pattern to java date pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689247/oracle-date-pattern-to-java-date-pattern)
>   [Default JDBC date format when reading date as a string from ResultSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700962/default-jdbc-date-format-when-reading-date-as-a-string-from-resultset)

In my java application, I have a date string coming from db in different-different formats each time **05-Feb-2013**, along with the format pattern **DD-MON-YYYY**.

I need to convert this **date string to java.util.Date**. Java's default **java.text.DateFormat** implementation, which is **java.text.SimpleDateFormat** will not work here as it can not understand oracle database's format pattern. My question here is

1) Is there any other implementation of **java.text.DateFormat** like **java.text.SimpleDateFormat** (which is an implementation of DatePattern after all), which can accept oracle db's format pattern and return java.util.Date?

or

2) Is there any utility to draw java simpledateformat pattern from oracle db format pattern?

or

3) Can it be achieved in any other way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you getting a *string* at all? Is your field not a date type in the database? Note that `SimpleDateFormat` certainly *will* work if you give it the right pattern...

Comment: This is the second such question this evening.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700962 Must be a homework assignment.

Comment: Is this strange API something that someone else designed and you are stuck with?  Can you show us an actual code sample?  It really seems odd that you wouldn't be able to let the database driver convert into java date objects like normal.

Comment: I have an xml comming from db. It is not through jdbc.
<TYPE_TRNY_COMPLETE_DATA><F_PRODUCT_ID>POKER</F_PRODUCT_ID><F_EVENT_CREATION_TIME>07-JAN-13</F_EVENT_CREATION_TIME><F_IS_REAL_TOURNAMENT>Y</F_IS_REAL_TOURNAMENT></TYPE_TRNY_COMPLETE_DATA>

Comment: Ick - dates in XML but not in ISO-8601?

Comment: How many formats do you need to cope with? Can you just have a map from Oracle pattern to SimpleDateFormat pattern? That would be simpler than writing code to convert automatically.

Comment: Please don't [post the same question twice](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14689247/266304); if you don't get useful answers, [improve you existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty).

Answer (score 0):

1) if you have 'datevalue' alogn with 'datepattern' you dont have a problem using `simpleDateFormatter`

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(datePatternfromOracle);
```

2)
    //do this for all values
    format = new SimpleDateFormat(datePatternFromOracle);
    format.format(dateValueFromOracle);

3) there are multiple ways, but this is straight forward

Comment: That does not work at all.  The assertion he makes in the question that java's dateformat does not understand oracle database format strings is correct.

Comment: Yes..you are right. I made it clear. SimpleDateFormat can not understand datePatternFromOracle

Answer (score 0):

If your value type is Date then first convert it into String by String DateStr = value.toString(); then use SimpleDateFormat class to format as follow : 
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(YourFormat);
then use this code to format as your wish 
formatter.format(DateStr);
Hope this will help you ..

Answer (score 0):

This [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) pattern should work for your sample date: `dd-MMM-yyyy`. You may need to set to locale to English for this to work.

You say that the dates are formatted differently each time. How can you hope to parse something if you don't know what the format is?